# Error while using optuna for hyper parameter optimization with huggingface trainer

Tags: pytorch, huggingface, optuna

**Information**
The problem arises in chapter:

Making Transformers Efficient in Production
Describe the bug
while training I am getting proper F1 score of 0.755940
image

while finding best fit value of alpha and temperature value for NER task f1 score is 0.096029 which is less than 0.1
image

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. compute metric is same as in huggingface NER tutorial.
2. Hyperparameter are for alpha and temperature.

```
def hp_space(trial):
return {"alpha": trial.suggest_float("alpha", 0, 1),
"temperature": trial.suggest_int("temperature", 2, 20)}

best_run = distil_roberta_trainer.hyperparameter_search(
n_trials=12, direction="maximize",backend="optuna", hp_space=hp_space)
```

**Expected behavior**
After the hyperparameter search the F1 score should be higher than baseline.

More details:https://github.com/nlp-with-transformers/notebooks/issues/115#issue-1860567807

Hyperparameter optimization giving less F1 score less than 0.1 while default value giving 0.75.
Want good parameter value which gives better result than baseline.